# Flash fallback player on mediaelement.js displays strangely on full screen

Tags: flash, mediaelement.js

Across all browsers that need it (does not support HTML5 video in .mp4 format natively), the Flash player displays the video duration strangely - the duration numbers are always a strangely aligned (00:  00) and there is no video progress/seek bar.

Screenshot attached, you'll see the numbers on the bottom right.
[Link to screenshot here](http://i787.photobucket.com/albums/yy160/WilsonChoy/screenshot.jpg)

Duration numbers work fine outside of fullscreen mode.

This behaviour can also be seen on the demo on the homepage of http://www.mediaelementjs.com/ on IE7 or IE8. I'm just wondering if this is expected because such features are not yet fully implemented or if its a bug with Flash player?

Answer (score 0):

If you are using the `FLVPlayback` class then it might be causing the problems. This class has a boolean named `fullScreenTakeOver` which makes videos behave strangely on fullscreen mode. To solve this problem set the `fullScreenTakeOver` parameter of the `FLVPlayback` object to false.